# How to make if statement with null parameter?

Tags: java, if-statement, null

How do you make an if statement check if something is null, and will return null if the if statement is true?

```
public String getMiddle(String word)
   {
      // I don't know if 'is null' or 'return null' are actually things
      if (is null){
         return null;
      }
   }
```

Also, what would be an example of an input that would make it null?

Comment: `if(word == null) return null;`

Comment: `if(word == null) return null;`

Comment: This is pretty fundamental to Java, so if your reference material doesn't cover this you need a better source to learn from.

Comment: @Aominè We think exactly the same way and at the same time XD.

Comment: `if(!word) { return null; }`

Comment: `if(!word) { return word; }` is also pretty succinct but less readable.

Comment: @Cyclonecode that won't even compile, since `word` is not a `boolean`.

Comment: This question and the answers are a catastrophe.

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of trouble if you don't get used to return `null`as an error state. You'd better throw a `NullPointerException`...

Comment: someone close this question as i have my answer, am being demeaned, and losing reputation ;(

Comment: You can delete the question, which I heartily recommend.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot as you all have put in 'much effort' to answer this question.

Comment: Well, I flagged it for low quality.

Comment: thank you for helping me to remove this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aominè and litelite both said(in the same way at the same time), you can just do this:

```
if(word == null) return null;
```

And your second question:

> Also, what would be an example of an input that would make it null?

If you call the method like `getMiddle(null)`, then that would be possible.

Here are a bunch of ways to check if a word is null:

1:

```
private static void getWord(String str){
    try {
        if(!str.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Your word was null.");
    }
}
```

2:

```
private static void getWord(String str){
    try {
        if(!str.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Your word was null.");
    }
}
```

3:

```
private static void getWord(String str){
    try {
        if(str != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Your word was null.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tommy of course you can. What's wrong with the comments full of wrong information?

Comment: @Tommy `getMiddle(null)`. Jeez.

Comment: @Tommy well, you know what they say about assuming.

Comment: @Aominè I have edited my post. I thought the OP meant input through Scanner, which *is* impossible.